# Why some exchanges enforce that you send the total quantity (fill qty + open qty) when changing the order size?

Tags: exchange, order-handling, order

Is it to protect against overfills? Can anyone explain in simple terms?

Comment: The fill quantity and the open quantity may have changed in the meantime, but the total is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have an order with 10 shares open. Now you want to cancel it down to 6 shares. If you send just the **open quantity** you can have the following scenario:

- Reduce to 6 sent
- 3 shares got executed by the exchange while the reduce above was in-flight
- The exchange finally receives and processes the reduce, bringing the open quantity now to 6
- The remaining 6 shares are executed

Final situation: your order had 9 shares executed, even thought you wanted to reduce from 10 to 6. That was probably what you did not want.

Now if the exchange is requesting **total quantity** instead of open quantity:

- Reduce to 6 sent
- 3 shares got executed by the exchange while the reduce above was in-flight
- The exchange finally receives and processes the reduce, bringing the total quantity now to 3 instead of 6. That's because the 6 you sent was the total quantity and since now there are 3 shares executed, the open quantity must be 3 (open quantity = total quantity - executed quantity).
- The remaining 3 shares are executed

The final situation is that your order had 6 shares executed, probably the maximum exposure you wanted.

**So total quantity avoids overfills.** It is a more conservative way to reduce an open order.